# use computer to proxy android network

Tags: android, android-networking, android-framework, android-debug, adb

I am developing an Android app, and testing that on a real device.

I have a localhost server set up on my computer, and I want to the device to make request via my computer so that can access to this localhost environment in my computer.

I'm wondering if there is any tool in the adb shell that could allow me to proxy all network activity of the device by my computer, so it can access my localhost service?

NOTE: I know it works on emulator, I am just asking if this is possible on a real device.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install Fiddler on your computer, then on your android device connect to WiFi, long press your wifi configuration and choose modify network, then choose show advanced options and set the proxy field to your PC's IP address

Comment: For reference, the WiFi proxy settings in Android affect only the web browser and not applications, so this is not in fact a correct answer. Source? Because when I go into the connection settings in Android, it says right above the proxy field "HTTP proxy used by browser but may not be used by other applications".

Comment: Keyword there 'may'. Just as it 'may' be dependent on the rom you are using. I have used this method several times successfully.

Comment: I'm surprised that a fellow Brit doesn't read "may not" as "can not" :D, fair enough, but I have a Nexus 6 and 2 S5's in front of me running; 5.1.1, 5.0 and 4.4.2 respectively and it certainly doesn't work on any of those. My point is not to berate your answer, but to simply point out that with some pretty popular devices on stock, current ROMs it may not work, and my above comment is why. If I could edit my comment to say yours is partially correct, I would.